# Animating an oval moving towards another oval in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a game in Java where there is a ball (player) and other balls which are supposed to reach this player (enemies, etc). The player can move with the arrow keys to escape these enemies. I calculated the math to find the new X and Y positions of the enemy after the player moves, but I cannot find a way to animate these movements smoothly. I tried using threads, but it was not working correctly so I removed some of its code. There is also supposed to be a method to create new enemies at new positions and/or at different times once the game has started, but I wasn't able to get the timer to work. Here is the code for the program so far.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class game implements Runnable {

    JFrame frame;
    int myX = 400;
    int myY = 400;

    //x and y of second oval
    int X2 = 200;
    int Y2 = 200;


    Canvas canvas;
    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    boolean running = true;

    public game() {
        frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        panel.add(canvas);
        canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                moveIt(evt);
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        canvas.requestFocus();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (running = true) {
            Paint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game ex = new game();
        new Thread(ex).start();
    }
    public void Paint() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        Paint(g);
        bufferStrategy.show();

    }

    protected void Paint(Graphics2D g) {
        //paints the two ovals
        g.fillOval(myX, myY, 30, 30);
        g.fillOval(X2,Y2, 30, 30);
    }

    public void moveIt(KeyEvent evt) {
     switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
    //calculates positions for second oval
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                myY += 10;
                X2 = (int) ((X2 + myX) * 0.5);
                Y2 = (int) ((Y2 + myY) * 0.5);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                myY -= 10;
                X2 = (int) ((X2 + myX) * 0.5);
                Y2 = (int) ((Y2 + myY) * 0.5);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                myX -= 10;
                X2 = (int) ((X2 + myX) * 0.5);
                Y2 = (int) ((Y2 + myY) * 0.5);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                myX += 10;
                X2 = (int) ((X2 + myX) * 0.5);
                Y2 = (int) ((Y2 + myY) * 0.5);

                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any help I can get with the animations of the balls and the method.

Comment: Do you want the ball to keep moving for as long as the key is held down?  Or just move a little then stop?  Or continue moving even after the key is released?  Do you want it to speed up then slow down?  I believe you need to think a whole lot more about what you're actually trying to do.  But yes, you're going to need threads.  And you probably want to capture KEY PRESSED and KEY RELEASED events.  This is far too broad a question to really cover in a succinct answer here.

Comment: I want to keep the ball moving always.

Comment: So you'll have to store its velocity (possibly even separate variables for horizontal and vertical components of velocity) and work out how the velocity should change when you press a key.  Then you'll need a thread that recalculates the ball's position based on its velocity, and redraws the ball.

Comment: How would you do it every x milliseconds or so?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  Whole books have been written about this stuff.  You won't get a satisfying answer on Stack Overflow - I suggest you do some reading.

Comment: Where though would I read this?

Comment: Gee, if only there was some kind of web site that we could use to help us find information on the Internet.